# Error retrieving account java.lang.IllegalStateException: No current tap-and-pay account

Tags: java, android

I've been trying to run my code and I get this error. The app just crashes and it doesn't matter what virtual device I use. My app doesn't have any kind of pay services what-so-ever. With that said, what does this error even refer to and how is it fixed?

**Logcat:**

```
09-30 23:51:25.945 2632-11033/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/SeTransactionSyncTask: Error retrieving account
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: No current tap-and-pay account
        at anbe.b(:com.google.android.gms@12874026@12.8.74 (040700-204998136):3)
        at anbe.a(:com.google.android.gms@12874026@12.8.74 (040700-204998136):1)
        at anvc.a(:com.google.android.gms@12874026@12.8.74 (040700-204998136):28)
        at com.google.android.gms.tapandpay.gcmtask.TapAndPayGcmTaskChimeraService.b(:com.google.android.gms@12874026@12.8.74 (040700-204998136):1)
        at com.google.android.gms.tapandpay.gcmtask.TapAndPayGcmTaskChimeraService.a(:com.google.android.gms@12874026@12.8.74 (040700-204998136):1)
        at com.google.android.gms.tapandpay.phenotype.PhenotypeCommitIntentOperation.onHandleIntent(:com.google.android.gms@12874026@12.8.74 (040700-204998136):47)
        at com.google.android.chimera.IntentOperation.onHandleIntent(:com.google.android.gms@12874026@12.8.74 (040700-204998136):2)
        at dfm.a(:com.google.android.gms@12874026@12.8.74 (040700-204998136):8)
        at npz.a(:com.google.android.gms@12874026@12.8.74 (040700-204998136):9)
        at dfr.run(:com.google.android.gms@12874026@12.8.74 (040700-204998136):10)
        at dfo.run(:com.google.android.gms@12874026@12.8.74 (040700-204998136):9)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

These are the Java Thread lines that the error calls out. The specific thread lines for the errors are pointed out.

**ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162**

```
            try {
                task.run(); --------------------Line 1162
            } catch (RuntimeException x) {
                thrown = x; throw x;
            } catch (Error x) {
                thrown = x; throw x;
            } catch (Throwable x) {
                thrown = x; throw new Error(x);
            } finally {
                afterExecute(task, thrown);
            }
```

**ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636**

```
 /** Delegates main run loop to outer runWorker. */
    public void run() {
        runWorker(this);--------------------Line 636
    }
```

**Thread.java.764**

```
/**
     * If this thread was constructed using a separate
     * <code>Runnable</code> run object, then that
     * <code>Runnable</code> object's <code>run</code> method is called;
     * otherwise, this method does nothing and returns.
     * <p>
     * Subclasses of <code>Thread</code> should override this method.
     *
     * @see     #start()
     * @see     #stop()
     * @see     #Thread(ThreadGroup, Runnable, String)
     */
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (target != null) {
            target.run(); --------------------Line 764
        }
    }
```

The error occurred when I changed the following adapter code to address the previous error below that I had. If I revert it, the tap-and-pay error goes away.

> RecyclerViewAdapter cannot be applied to given types; required: Cursor
>   found: Context, reason: actual and formal argument lists differ
>   in length

I changed it From:

```
   if (mAdapter == null) {
        mAdapter = new HistoryRecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), null);
    }
```

To:

```
   if (mAdapter == null) {
        mAdapter = new HistoryRecyclerViewAdapter(null);
    }
```

Comment: Are you using an in-app payment plugin?

Comment: Nope, not at all. My app just uses a SQLite database to store user-entered information about their vehicle that outputs what vehicle maintenance they should perform.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50652370/setransactionsynctask-error-retrieving-account-java-lang-illegalstateexception
but no answer yet :-/

Comment: Yeah.. I was hoping there would be a development since then. I found that the error happened after I tried to fix code to address a previous error. I've edited my post with the details.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this issue , i am also facing similar issue

Comment: Perhaps https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/3470787?hl=en